# Change a image when list box selected item is changed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list box with id of 'availmap' containing filename of images the path is maps/image.jpg

I also have a image control with id of 'map' that I would like to change to the selected image using the onclick event of the list box

this is the js I have tried and can not figure out why it won't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ChgImg() {
    var list = document.getElementById('availmap');
    var indx = list.selectedIndex;
    var img = list[indx].value;
    var id = document.getElementById('map');
    id.src="maps/" + img;
```

}

This is the image tag and the listbox code

```
<div id='avail' style='position:fixed;left:500px;top:0;z-index:0;text-align:center;bgcolor='#00b0e6';>
<span style='position:fixed;left:540px;top:30px;width:250px;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;background-color:#00b0e6;border: 1px #000000 solid;'>Availible Maps</span>  </div>
<form action='jobs.php' target='joblist' style='position:fixed;left:500px;top:101px;'></td>

<select id='availmap' name='availmap' size='10' style='width: 250px;position:fixed;left:540px;top:51px;' onchange='ChgImg()'>
EOY;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mapresult))
{ 
 echo "<option value=\"".$row['ID']."\">".$row['AssocMap']."</option>\n  ";
}

echo "</select>";

echo "</form>";

echo "<img id='map' src='' alt='' style='position:absolute;left:800px;top:30px;width:260px;height:185px;border: 1px #000000 solid;'>";
```

I'm sure it is something relatively simple I am missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're javascript was almost correct, just use `id.src=img;`

Complete javascript:

```
function ChgImg() {
        var list = document.getElementById('availmap');
        var indx = list.selectedIndex;
        var img = list[indx].value;
        var id = document.getElementById('map');
        id.src=img;
}
```

I would use the change event instead of the click event. Don't forget to add the code in the head of the page.

**UPDATE**

The javascript you're using works fine as you can see in the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/p0wc8h2u/2/). However, I don't think you're passing a valid value for the src of the image in the code you provide (`value=\"".$row['ID']."\`). It seems you're using the ID of the row for the value (usually a number) when you actually need to use a valid src for the image (for example `http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg`). Do you have the url of the images stored in some other column of the row? If so, use it instead of `$row['ID']`

Also, please check your HTML. There are a few mistakes that you should correct (most of them single quotes badly closed).

I've also modified your html a bit in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p0wc8h2u/2/)

Comment: This also does nothing if I make the src in the image tag 'maps/acoustic_guitar_diagram.jpg' the image shows,  if I make the last line in the js id='maps/acoustic_guitar_diagram.jpg' the image shows on change but if I use id=img nothing no change at all I changed to onclick="ChgImg()" this is making me nuts any other info I can provide please ask

Comment: @phpnoobie I don't really understand where you're having trouble. You just have to change that line in your code and use the `onchange` event. It should work. Anyway, create a jsfiddle, update the post with the link and I'll check it out.

Comment: I do not know how to use jsfiddle to post this may I post the full page here?  also does it matter if I am using php and mysql in this endevor?

Comment: @phpnoobie update the post with all the information you think may help

Comment: I have updated the original post and hope it is something simple I am missing here

Comment: I have updated the original post and hope it is something simple I am missing here @acontell

Comment: @phpnoobie I've updated my answer. I don't think there's any problem with the script, I think the problem is the value you're using in the options of the select.

Comment: Thank you ever so much that was the problem***********Tried to move this but not enough reputation

Answer (score 3):

You should use **[Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)**

> Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on
>   the specified element.
>
> ```
> element.setAttribute(name, value);
> ```
>
> **Params**
>
> - name is the name of the attribute as a string.
> - value is the desired new value of the attribute.

So, change your code to this:

```
function ChgImg() {
        var list = document.getElementById('availmap');
        var indx = list.selectedIndex;
        var img = list[indx].value;
        var id = document.getElementById('map');
        id.setAttribute("src", img);
```